# Service endpoint not found?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

Seem to run into a service endpoint not found problem when trying to get from my service.

if I try http://localhost:8000/hello/help I should expect to see `<string>You entered help <string>` but I only get the no endpoint instead? I havent touched my config files at all and I am just hosting from a console app.

Host:

```
namespace Host
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
            WebServiceHost host =
            new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1),
            binding,
            "http://localhost:8000/hello");
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world service");
            Console.WriteLine("Press <RETURN> to end service");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Service1:

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(string value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
```

IService1:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{value}")]
    string GetData(string value);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the / from {value} and make sure it is listed as an `OperationContract`. It should be:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{value}")]
[OperationContract]
```

The base URL will come through with the trailing slash, so you are really looking for `http://localhost:8000/hello//help` in the current code

Comment: Hey Justin nice to see you on again, /{value} is because my url is: http://localhost:8000/hello no end slash / I think it can be either or but regardless taking it away does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Garrith I have updated my answer, I noticed that you are also missing the OperationContractAttribute.

Comment: @Garrith Out of curiosity, can you try it with and without the slash. By everything that I have seen, the first value is never prefixed with a slash, so I am curious as to whether it does or does not make a difference?

Comment: yup makes no difference however... doing //help only returns help! But localhost:8000/hello/help also returns help!

Answer (score 0):

A stab in the dark ... by default, arbitrary processes are not permitted to listen on network ports.

When IIS is installed, the account that runs IIS is given permission - if you want other applications run by other accounts (console applications, windows services) to be able to listen to a port, you need to grant the permission.

Check out the [`netsh add urlacl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command as a starting point.

Comment: But my vs2010 runs under administrator?

Comment: Being administrator doesn't mean you have all privileges - just that you have the power to grant them to yourself. I was recently working on a windows service that self hosted a WCF service (to allow for reconfiguration on the fly) - my service was inaccessible until I used netsh to grant the permission. I was using VS2010 running on Windows Server 2008 R2 at the time.